# em.createNativeQuery executa primeiro do que o em.persist e agora?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com Hibernate + Spring mv. o spring cuida da dependência do EntityManager para meu DAO, porem tenho o seguinte problema.

- eu persisto um objeto chamado User
- depois eu executo createNativeQuery com "insert into tabela1 (campo1, campo2) select campo1, campo2 from User"

com isso notei que na tabela1 não estava registrando o User, fui conferir habilitando show_sql e no console o hibernate executa primeiro o createNativeQuery depois o persist, independente da ordem que os dois foram escritos.

Existe alguma forma de configurar o hibernate pra que ele mantenha a ordem?

Comment: Poderia colocar o código na pergunta para olharmos? :) Inclua também a saída do show_sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é causado porque muitas das operações comuns são armazenadas em uma espécie de fila em memória, que geralmente é descarregada no banco de uma só vez ao fechar o `EntityManager`. O Hibernate tenta assim otimizar o acesso ao banco de dados. Porém, queries nativas não passam por essa fila e para o SGBD é como se o primeiro comando nunca tivesse ocorrido.

O ideal nesse caso é executar o método `flush()` após o `persist()` para forçar que os comandos aguardando na fila foram enviados ao banco de dados, neste caso a inserção.

Comment: Nice! Isso mesmo, Muito obrigado =)